# EmberJS {{action}} and nested li

Tags: ember.js

I am having an odd issue with the action helper on nested li elements.

For example

```
<ul>
   <li><a {{action someAction target="view"}}>Link 1</a></li>
   <ul>
       <li><a {{action someAction target="view"}}>Link 2</a></li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

The Link 1 action will fire, however the Link 2 action does not (no errors in the console either). I was previously using the Em.Button to workaround this however I understand that is now being depreciated.

**EDIT:**

From looking further into this it appears to be an issue when the nested `ul` is a bootstrap `dropdown-menu` in a nav bar.

Has anyone else seen this kind of issue?

Comment: Indeed, that's weird, this should work IMHO. Would it be possible to add a jsfiddle of your example ? It's too difficult here to help you without more context.

Answer (score 5):

Your second `<ul></ul>` should be wrapped by `<li></li>`:

```
<ul>
   <li><a {{action someAction target="view"}}>Link 1</a></li>
   <li>
       <ul>
          <li><a {{action someAction target="view"}}>Link 2</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. It was just a typo in my example however as the actual template I am using is much larger.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I ran into a similar issue recently and got it to work like this, with an empty href and placing the action on the "li" instead of the "a".

```
<ul>
   <li {{action someAction target="view"}}><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
   <ul>
       <li {{action someAction target="view"}}><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```